# Share functions between controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm assuming this is quite straightforward, but how can I have global functions that I can access in my controllers by storing the function in the '.run' phase?

Quite simply, a button is clicked in the DOM that triggers the global function that is called in the appropriate controller..

I've tried various methods and would like a really simple approach to this that helps to minimise the amount of code I've currently got. See below:

```
**HTML**

<input data-ng-click="clearSignInError()" data-ng-model="email" 
type="email"
id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"   
required>

**JS**

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {

    $rootScopecope.clearSignInError = function () {
        $rootScope.loginError = null;
        $rootScope.loginSuccess = null;
    };

}]);

app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', '$state', '$rootScope'
    function($scope, Auth, $state, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.clearSignInError()

}]);
```

Comment: you can use factory or inject controller

Comment: has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370161/reuse-function-in-two-different-comtrollers-in-angularjs/35370771#35370771

Comment: I will check this out now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a factory instead of hooking up with rootScope. In this way, you can include your factory as a dependency in any controller you want. Here's a video demonstration which might help you to get started:

[Factories In AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXu9xmSIhRs&list=PLYxzS__5yYQmX2bItSRCqwiQZn5dIL1gt&index=24)

Comment: If this is the case, I assume I will not need to use all of this code in the factory:     $rootScopecope.clearSignInError = function () {
        $rootScope.loginError = null;
        $rootScope.loginSuccess = null;
    };. Instead, I would use $scope.loginError = null; $scope.loginSuccess = null; and store these in a function that is called in the controller using $scope.clearSignInError?

Comment: Yes. You can do that.

Comment: But that's not called using $scope.clearSignInError. Its called using your factory name.

Comment: I'm trying this now, but I'm also using another 'return' method in my existing factory for another function. It's saying 'unreachable code' at the start of the 'return' method for some reason - everything else seems fine but just want to check this issue out first before trying it.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet might be to use Services or Factories, and then inject these as dependencies when needed throughout your application.

[Angular Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

[Angular Factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Edit: Added an example service in this plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/zqWS9gkTsm2OF1FTb24Z?p=preview

```
app.service('AuthService', function() {
    this.loginSuccess = function() {
        // do stuff when login is successful
    }

    this.loginError = function() {
        // handle login errors here
    }

    this.clearLoginError = function() {
        console.log("Clear Login Error");
        alert("Clear Login Error");
    }
});

// modified your controller
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Auth', 'AuthService', '$state', '$rootScope', function($scope, Auth, AuthService, $state, $rootScope) {

    $scope.clearSignInError = AuthService.clearLoginError;

}]);

**HTML**
<input data-ng-click="clearSignInError()" data-ng-model="email"
type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
```

Comment: I did try the factory option although I must have got it wrong. Based on my above code, how could i achieve what I need setting up a service? I'm simply removing an error on screen following an incorrect form submission when the user clicks back on the input box.

Comment: Just been trying the new code, although I'm getting a red line under $scope.clearSignInError() in my controller?

Comment: Sorry that line should be `$scope.clearSignInError = AuthService.clearLoginError();` and the HTML should be `data-ng-click="clearSignInError"`

Comment: Still no luck I'm afraid, I've tried the following: 'app.service('AuthService', function() {

    this.clearSignInError = function($scope) {
        $scope.loginError = null;
        $scope.loginSuccess = null;
    };

});' and in my controller: '$scope.clearSignInError = AuthService.clearSignInError();'

Comment: I have updated my answer with a plunkr for you, so you can see it in action.

Comment: I've just ran through the code and can see how it works, although I'm including a '$scope.loginError = null;' to remove an error message in an ng-if command div (ignore the $scope.loginSuccess = null; as that shouldn't be there!). It just doesn't seem to work as I seem to be getting an injection error pop up in my console, which I think is causing the problems: "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=<div class="ng-scope" data-ui-view="">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20AuthService

Comment: That error suggests that you haven't registered AuthService as a provider. How and where are you registering your application? (it will look like `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

Comment: Okay, I've had that error before so this may provide more light into my past problems I've had with it. Here's the code: var app = angular.module('routerApp', ['firebase', 'ui.router']);

Comment: So long as the `var app = ...` and `app.service(...` are in the same file, or where ever your `app.service(...` is can access `var app` it should just work? If you look in the Plunkr it works fine.

Comment: I will double check again, but I'm not sure if the fact that I'm including $scope in the service is causing the problems. I need to set the ng-if value to null on input click which is the reason I need to have the $scope in the service.

Comment: ahh yes, I dont think you can/should include scope in the service, that will error. If you need to set a scope value using the service, you can do as per this updated plunkr - https://plnkr.co/edit/zqWS9gkTsm2OF1FTb24Z?p=preview

Comment: I've tried again with kinds of changes and still no luck. It just seems the function won't trigger using $scope in a factory

Comment: Okay, I've just tried that as well with no luck afraid. All I need to do is set the ng-if value on the DOM to null using a globally accessible function using $scope.